# Signing using ElGamal or Encrypting using private key

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sjcl

I'm using SJCL js library:
How do I use the elGamal algorithm to prove that a user posses the private key based on the public key? I also utilize the ECCDH part so I can't just use ECDSA.

I want everybody to be able to verify that the user, who posses that private key actually wrote the message, actually made the request, by using his/her public key to decrypt the message.

request message -> encrypt with private key -> send it -> everybody can decrypt the message by using his public key, proving he actually made the request

I am very new to cryptography, I have learned that in asymmetric you can use the private key to encrypt the file but I can't seem to find this tool on SJCL.

I have attached a screenshot of my attempt below please let me know where I am doing it wrong. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTWtZ.png)

Comment: You seem to be confusing signature generation and encryption although I don't get the following "I also utilize the ECCDH part so I can't just use ECDSA.". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes I am very confused and may think something is for something else since I am very new to asymmetric encryption. SJCL has elGamal and ECDSA, their ElGamal algorithm also includes DH which can be used to produce a shared key without exchanging key at all (right?). I both need a way to encrypt using another user's(user2) public key so I(user1) can send him(user2) a message, and also to encrypt using my(user1) own private key, so I can send a message for everyone to see. All this I need to do with javascript on a webpage (not nodejs or npm)

Comment: On their wiki, https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/wiki/Asymmetric-Crypto it is specifically said that signing is done using ECDSA and not ElGamal, but I need the encryption capability of ElGamal ( I am sending encrypted message ) but at the same time the private key possesion-proving capability of ECDSA, how do I do that?

Comment: ElGamal doesn't have signature generation capabilities. You need to encrypt (using ElGamal or ECIES) using the public key of the other party, and to sign with your own private key (using ECDSA). So in total two key pairs, one of the receiver and one of the sender. There are no shortcuts possible where you can use just one key pair for this.

Comment: This is what I feared to be the answer, how do I bind the 2 key pairs together without a centralized server? is there a way? I want the elGamal key pair to be proven to be the genuine partner of the DSA key pair, is this possible?

Comment: Or, please, do you know an algorithms that fits what I need, which is, the possibility of encryption with both public key and private key ?

Comment: an EC algorithm if possible, I want a short public key length like on bitcoin

Comment: Encryption with a private key is nonsense. Encryption is what you use to obtain confidentiality, and anybody can have the public key to decrypt. Even in the latest RSA standards they have gone out of their way to explain that signature generation is *not* encryption with a private key, even if a similar operation is used (as you can use the same trapdoor problem). The DH problem doesn't have this "feature" even if encryption with a private key would make sense in the first place.

Comment: A server has bunch of data sent to a certain public key(used as address) by another user, encrypted with the DH shared key. After he gets those data, the server will delete the data. So I want to have a verification that the requesting user is actually the one possessing the private key corresponding to the public key.

The data encrypted by the private key would just be request keywords, not any sensitive data. I would also like to use this encryption to send public messages that can be read by anyone and can be validated to be from the public key that it claims

Comment: OHHHH I get it now, I don't need an "encryption" with private key. All I need is an asymmetric encryption (like elGamal) with capability of signature (like DSA). This way a public message can be sent unencrypted but with signature to prove it is from the claimed sender.

Comment: Is there any algorithm capable of doing this?

Comment: Should I repost a new question?

Comment: If I could encrypt using DSA keys my problem would be solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162907/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-albertdiones).

Comment: I am sorry to say this but if your understanding of cryptography is this limited you should read and learn a lot more before trying to implement any kind of crypto scheme!

Comment: Hi Nils, I've already figured it out thanks to Maarten, where I was wrong is that assuming elGamal generated keys are not usable for ECDSA, all I need was a proof that the user holds the private key of the public key he claims to be. Once I confirm that it works I'll post it as answer for other people (equally confused) as me, could be helped.

Also yeah, I'm doing my best to study cryptography and I'll continue to do so for quite some time.